# How can I send email through a bash script using a different SMTP server and credentials?

Tags: bash, smtp

I have a script which is performing a MySQL dump, and I want it to send an email if and when it fails. How can I make the sending of the email use TLS with a username/password, a special port, and an alternate SMTP host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sendEmail: http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/ it allows you to specify an SMTP server and port using the `-s` flag. TLS can be enabled using `-o tls=yes` and a username and password can be set using `-o username=...` and `-o password=...` respectively.